# ttyS1/uart1 initialised but not accessible through /dev/ttyS1

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, kernel, davinci

Apologies if this is the wrong place for this question, I'm not currently sure which level the problem is at so I'm hedging my bets a tad.

System is a LeopardBoard DM368 running TI's own SDK / LSP / BusyBox kernel.

By default the system has one UART enabled, UART0, mounted as /dev/ttyS0 which is also used/invoked via the bootargs `console=ttyS0,115200n8 earlyprintk`.

We want to enable UART1 as /dev/ttyS1, so have gone through the low-level board initialisation code which sets up the pinmux, clocks, etc.

On booting, the low-level init reports (via printk's I added in) that it's enabled the UART1, and the driver code reports happiness too:

```
[    0.547812] serial8250.0: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x1c20000 (irq = 40) is a 16550A
[    0.569849] serial8250.0: ttyS1 at MMIO 0x1d06000 (irq = 41) is a 16550A
```

However, the port does not (reliably) appear in /dev/, and there are discrepancies with its status (flow control bits) which I suspect may be causing it to hang / never transmit:

```
cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:16550A mmio:0x01C20000 irq:40 tx:97998 rx:0 CTS|DSR
1: uart:16550A mmio:0x01D06000 irq:41 tx:0 rx:0 DSR
```

If I try to modify it from the command line I get an error:

```
>: stty -F /dev/ttyS1
stty: /dev/ttyS1: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Bizarrely, if I change the bootargs to `console=ttyS1,115200n8 earlyprintk` the port works perfectly, and ttyS0 is initialised correctly and works too:

```
cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:16550A mmio:0x01C20000 irq:40 tx:0 rx:0 CTS|DSR
1: uart:16550A mmio:0x01D06000 irq:41 tx:11563 rx:0 RTS|DTR|DSR
```

Now, that would be fine, but our bootloader must use UART0 so it would be nice to keep all the console stuff on ttyS0 and have ttyS1 for our secondary comms.

**Edit to add**: I inserted a couple of printk's into serial_core.c and it seems like uart_open() is never being called for ttyS1, I'm assuming it's something in the Linux init/startup sequence that needs modifying?

I'll state now that I'm not a hardy Linux hacker so it's entirely possible I've missed some obvious/dumb thing in either the kernel code, initialisation sequence, etc.

**Any thoughts greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a nice chap over on the Linux board solved it, I need to insert a `mknod /dev/ttyS1 c 4 65` somewhere.

Quite why this (apparently) happens for `ttyS0` or whichever port is `console` I don't know, but right now all that matters is **it works**!

Comments / further info on the reasons why would be welcome for my own knowledge / future generations.